Turborepo, AdonisJS, error sharing type between backend application and packages
I would like to use AdonisJS in a mono repo managed by turbo repo.
I have an admin app (React) and a backend app (AdonisJS).
I have a type package to share my types between backend and frontend.
In my frontend I can import my types and constants without any problem.
But in AdonisJS I get a module not found error.
I don't understand why.
I create test repository.
Ts config of adonis:
{
  "extends": "@adonisjs/tsconfig/tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./",
    "outDir": "./build"
  }
}

Ts config admin (React):
{
  "extends": "./base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}

Base config:
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "inlineSources": false,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "preserveWatchOutput": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}


and here's the blocking code:
import router from '@adonisjs/core/services/router'
import { User, roles } from '@repo/type' // <- Unable to locate '@repo/type' module or type declarations correspondantes.ts(2307)


router.get('/', async () => {
  const user: User = {
    id: '1',
    role: roles.admin,
  }
  return {
    user,
  }
})

I have tried different tsconfig.json but nothing works.
